# Calculating work done in Thermodynamics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, work

[image]

Unless I am mistaken, to find the work done going from Point $1$ to Point $2$, the textbook noted I needed to find the area under the curve of the region in blue. However, if I'm meant to find the area under this curve from the point $V_1 = \text{Point 1}$ to $V_2 = \text{Point 2}$, it would certainly be the area under the curve to the axis, so it would be the area of the blue region plus the area of the green region. Why is it the blue region in this case? Hopefully I've misinterpreted or something..

Comment: I have revised my answer to, hopefully, more directly answer your question. Let me know if you need any further clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going from just point 1 to point 2 then you need the blue area and the green area for the reasons you have given.

If you then also include going to point 3, or even then completing the cycle, then you just want the blue area
 This is because going from 2 to 3 involves adding the negative of the green area, so 
$$\text{blue}+\text{green}-\text{green}=\text{blue}$$

Answer (score 1):

***Why is it the blue region in this case? The process from 1 to 2 is an isothermal expansion.***

If the text book is saying it wants the the blue area, then it is not asking for the work from 1 to 2, but the net work done for the complete cycle (1-2-3-1). I suggest you re-read the book and make sure what it is they are asking for. If it is saying the blue region is the work from 1 to 2, then it is in error.

FYI, the net work (blue area) is determined as follows:

For a reversible (constant temperature) isothermal process, heat is taken in and an equal amount of work is done. The work done is positive (done by the gas on the surroundings) and is the entire area under the curve 1 to 2. For 1 mole of an ideal gas, that work is

$$W_{1-2}=RTln\frac{V_2}{V_{1}}$$

Note that since $V_{2}>V_{1}$ the work is positive

But the process in going from 2 to 3 is an isobaric (constant pressure) compression where heat is rejected and the work is negative (done by the surroundings on the gas). The negative work is the area under the 2 to 3 process path (the rectangle). That work is given by

$$W_{2-3}=P_{2}(V_{1}-V_{2})$$

Since $V_{2}>V_{1}$ the work is negative.

No work is done going from 3 back to 1 because there is no change in volume.

The net work done in the cycle is the algebraic sum of the work from 1 to 2 and from 2 to 3, or

$$W_{1-2-3-1}=W_{1-2}+W_{2-3}=RTln\frac{V_2}{V_{1}}+P_{2}(V_{1}-V_{2})$$

Which equals the blue area.

Hope this helps.